# how can I make a Regex to match prefix and multiple sufix at same time?

Tags: regex

Ive encounter this problem.

I need to clean some corrupted data that has the following pattern:

```
VALUES (  1', NULL, 'Smith', 'Jackson',...
VALUES (  2', 'jon@doe', 'John', 'Doe',...
```

Basically, I need to remove the extra `'`, for that I first need to match it...

So I came up with this

```
(?<=VALUES \(  \d+)(.*')(?=(, '[a-zA-Z])||(^NULL,$))
```

Unfortunately, it's not matching anything, the `\d+` is specially problematic.

Any idea how I can isolate the 1`'`, 2`'`, ... (only the `'` after the number that can have N digits) and be able to match the prefix for `'string` or `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use

```
\b(VALUES\s*\(\s*\d+)'(?=,\s*(?:NULL|'[a-zA-Z]))
```

*Explanation*

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1** (to be used in the replacement keeping this part)

  - `VALUES\s*\(\s*\d+` Match VALUES, `(` and then match 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `'` Match the `'` that you want to remove
- `(?=,\s*(?:NULL|'[a-zA-Z])` Positive lookahead to make sure that directly to the right is a comma followed by NULL or `'` and a char a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sCKVb7/1)

In the replacement use group 1.

*Output*

```
VALUES (  1, NULL, 'Smith', 'Jackson',...
VALUES (  2, 'jon@doe', 'John', 'Doe',...
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the pattern/trend you showed continues for the entire `VALUES` clause, I would recommend the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:   (VALUES\s+\(\s*\d+)',
Replace: $1,
```

### Demo

Note: Another possibility, perhaps simpler than above, might be available if the stray single quote appearing after the numbers also happens to appear in a single column.  If so, then you could do a block select of that column across the entire `VALUES` clause and just delete it away.